# Bash dialog displays unknown text

Tags: bash, dialog

I am trying to use dialog on bash but I get some extra text on the screen.

this is the line for dialog:

```
dialog --title "Hello" --msgbox 'Hello world!' 6 20
```

and this is the output:

[image]

any idea why this is happening?

Comment: This has something to do with your locale settings and the terminal emulator you are using. It would be easier if you mentioned what those were.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like `dialog` is using box-drawing characters which your terminal emulator doesn't understand properly (among other issues).

For a quick work-around, you can tell `dialog` to use <kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>+</kbd> to draw boxes, or to not try to draw them at all:

```
dialog --ascii-lines --title "Hello" --msgbox 'Hello world!' 6 20
dialog --no-lines    --title "Hello" --msgbox 'Hello world!' 6 20
```

Answer (score 2):

For posterity, if the terminal is putty you can change the terminal type from `xterm` to `linux` (before you connect).

To do this on the `PuTTY Configuration` screen for your connection navigate to `Connection->Data->Terminal-type String` and change the value from `xterm` to `linux`.  After that 'dialog' should display correctly.

Answer (score 0):

(necro)

This somehow works for me.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$LANG" =~ 'UTF-8' ]]
then
  export NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS=0
else
  export NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS=1
fi

dialog --title "Confirmation"  --yesno "It works?" 5 30
```

Comment: "This somehow works" is even more frustrating for a future reader than no explanation at all.

Comment: bringing up and old post from the grave :p

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Not meaning to necro-post, but I just had one of my techs bring a situation like this to me.

The trick that worked for us is;

1. Left-click on the PuTTY symbol in the upper-left corner of the PuTTY
   terminal.
2. Click "Change Settings"
3. Highlight "Translation" in the left-pane of the "PuTTY Reconfiguration" window.
4. Change "Remote Character Set" from "UTF-8" to "ISO-8859-1:1998 (Latin-1, West Europe)"
5. Click "Apply".
6. Re-run your ***dialog*** application.

Hope that helps.